# Laravel 5 migration - foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

I'm having problems with running my migration. I have a mysql database with some tables. The specific table is `product_blender`. Some fields in the table are like this:

> - id (PK)
> - area_id (FK)
> - inhabitants (varchar)
> - heating_type_id (FK)
> - ...

Now I would like to create another table called `installateur_types`. The table needs to contain a **PK** and a **varchar field**. I would also like to create a **FK** in `product_blender` table to the **id** of my newly created tabel.

This is what I've done:

**Created migration to create a table:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('installateur_types', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('type');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('installateur_types');
}
```

Run the migration, this was successful. Table was created with correct fields.

**Then I've created the migration to add a FK field to the product_blender table**.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('product_blenders', function ($table) {
        $table->integer('installateurtype_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('installateurtype_id')->references('id')->on('installateur_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    //
}
```

When I now run the migration I get the following error:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `product_blenders` table existed previously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `products_blender` table is not empty, then when you add a new column which is not null (which is the default for eloquent), it will be assuming some default value on its own. This value may not be available in the table this new column is referring to, causing the foreign key constraint to fail.

One of the way to get around this is to give a default value to the new column or **just make it nullable**.

```
$table->integer('installateurtype_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('installateurtype_id')->references('id')->on('installateur_types')->onDelete('cascade');
```

There is one other solution, which turns off this checks, which can be done using `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;')`. Then again turn that one for future with `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;')`. In you code you can do something like

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
$table->integer('installateurtype_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('installateurtype_id')->references('id')->on('installateur_types')->onDelete('cascade');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```